# NPM Failing on Trying to Find Shell Script

Tags: javascript, npm, command-line-interface

Console output on `npm run build` failure:

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

And the relevant npm file:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "jspm install && npm run build",
    "start": "http-server",
    "build": "./bin/build-code",
    "build-home": "./bin/build-home -dw",
    "build-common-deps": "./bin/build-common-deps -dw",
    "build-navbar": "./bin/build-navbar -dw",
    "build-root": "./bin/build-root -dw",
    "build-angular1": "./bin/build-angular1 -dw",
    "build-react": "./bin/build-react -w",
    "build-preact": "./bin/build-preact -dw",
    "build-vanilla": "./bin/build-vanillajs",
    "build-angular2": "./bin/build-angular2 -dw"
}
```

Looks like it's not understanding the pathing to the `./bin/build-code` script location. From what I understand, it looks for files from the `package.json`'s location? So, if the app has a `bin` folder in the same dir as `package.json`, then this is the correct pathing to the `build-code` script, which is within the bin folder. What gives? Using PowerShell to run `npm run build` if it matters.

P.S. I tried with basic Command Prompt - no changes. Someone running the same build (both of us just pulled from repo) on Cygwin said they had to "Change dos endings to unix", which doesn't tell me much and doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like `npm` is invoking batch scripts. Batch files are run in CMD.exe (even when invoked from PowerShell), which doesn't recognize `/` as a path separator. That's where the error message comes from.

Replace the forward slashes with `\` (or `\\` if they require escaping).